# Does enabling one of the `Accounting=` options in a systemd unit, cause it to be enabled for *all* units?

Tags: linux, systemd, cgroups

> CPUAccounting=
>
> Turn on CPU usage accounting for this unit. Takes a boolean
>              argument. Note that turning on CPU accounting for one unit will
>              also implicitly turn it on for all units contained in the same
>              slice and for all its parent slices and the units contained
>              therein.

Tree nodes can only have one parent.  So I assume it actually means "all its ancestor slices".

Does it mean that enabling `CPUAccounting` for one unit will enable it for *all* units?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns it on for sibling cgroups, as well as it's parent cgroup (and their siblings, but not their children). This is because with cgroups, all cgroups on a level must have accounting enabled if a single cgroup has it enabled. For example, if you turn on cgroups accounting in a `example.service`, it'll enable accounting for the parent `system.service` and the other sibling services, as well as `user.slice` (since it's on the same level as `system.service`).

Comment: Ah. What confuses me about the doc is the word "contained". I guess it is using it in a non-transitive sense :-).  I.e. it means children of the slice, but not grand-children of the slice.

Comment: Seems odd that it has to propagate to all the siblings.  I think I understand it for stuff like `CPUWeight=`.  I guess the problem is that on older setups, CPU accounting "require[s] the CPU controller to be enabled (Linux 4.15+ using the unified hierarchy for resource control)".  Maybe `systemd` chooses to always propagate between siblings, or maybe they didn't want to make the doc too complicated :-).